# VBA: How can I tokenize an input in a cell

Tags: vba, time, tokenize

What I want to do is to convert time inputs in a cell to a specific format. Example:

```
"9" or "9 am" = 9:00:00 AM, which is the same as TIME(9, 0, 0)  
"9 30" = 9:30:00 AM = TIME(9, 30, 0)  
"4 30 pm" = 4:30:00 PM = TIME(16, 30, 0)
```

How can I achieve this in VBA?

Just a side note, this is actually my first time trying VBA.

Thanks.

Comment: You sure you want vba?  it can be done with formulas and custom formatting. Because as you know when asking for vba it is customary for the OP to show what they have tried so we might address the specific problem of the code.

Comment: VBA is preferable so I have a basis for learning. But since I don't have code, I guess formulas and custom formatting is ok.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so then please mark one as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can support some learning:

```
Function timm(str As String) As Double
Dim spltstr() As String
Dim hr As Integer
Dim min As Integer
Dim sec As Integer
hr = 0
min = 0
sec = 0
str = Replace(str, """", "")
spltstr = Split(str)
hr = spltstr(0)
If UCase(spltstr(UBound(spltstr))) = "PM" Then hr = hr + 12
If 1 <= UBound(spltstr) Then
    If IsNumeric(spltstr(1)) Then min = spltstr(1)
End If
timm = TimeSerial(hr, min, sec)


End Function
```

Place this in a module attached to the workbook.  It can then be called as a function directly on the worksheet or from another sub.

It will change the text to a number so you will still need to apply a custom number format to the cell if using this as a UDF.

[image]

As per you comments to do it in place then you would use a Worksheet_Change event.

First use a custom format on the whole column that you desire like `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.  The put this in the worksheet code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo getout
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsDate(Target.Value) Then
        Target = timm(Target.Value)
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
getout:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It calls the prior code and returns the number.  So as you leave edit mode it changes it to a time.

Comment: How can I do this on the same cell? If I input "9 am" in A1 can it be formatted to the format I want in A1 as well?

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use Split and TimeSerial. Here's an example to get you started.

```
Public Function ConvertToTime(ByVal Input_ As String) As Date

    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim lHour As Long, lMinute As Long

    'split the string into an array using space as a delimiter
    vaSplit = Split(Input_, Space(1))

    'The first element is the hour
    lHour = vaSplit(0)

    'If there's more than one element, the second element is the minute
    If UBound(vaSplit) > 0 Then lMinute = vaSplit(1)

    'if the last element is "pm", then add 12 to the hour
    If vaSplit(UBound(vaSplit)) = "pm" Then lHour = lHour + 12

    ConvertToTime = TimeSerial(lHour, lMinute, 0)

End Function
```